# Is there a way to break or exit out of the mounted hook cycle in vue.js after a specific operation/task is done?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently working on a project related to vuex. In order to launch the website, I want to trigger a function without creating a button in the html part of the vue file. I used mounted hook life cycle to call the javascript function, but I want to break out of the mounted lifecycle after a specific operation is done. Is it possible to break out of a mounted lifecycle once a certain operation is done? If yes, how do we do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use return.

Example:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(`Now you see me`);
  return;
  console.log(`Now you don't`);
}
```

Only the first console.log will be executed, return will exit you from the function.

Comment: Hi, return did not work in my case. I call a function which redirects me to the auth0 authentication page,etc. Even after I put return after calling my auth0login function, it continues with the mounted life cycle and keeps reloading the page (ie, it calls the auth0login() in a loop).

Comment: Could you paste your code here or in a codepen / jsfiddle? Makes it a bit easier if I see what you are looking at :)

Comment: ```mounted: function() {
          this.auth0login() //only call it when user not loggin  
          return;
 }
```

So it is the auth0login() which I call in mounted. After I call this function, it does not break out of the mounted lifecycle and keeps calling this function again and again. This function is responsible for authenticating a valid user. It sucessfully validates the user, but keeps refreshing the page (ie, it keeps calling the auth0login() again again-> reauthenticates it).

Comment: This function works fine, if I add a login button and then call the auth0login() from the button in the html file. It gives this issue when I remove the login button and when I try to call this function from the mounted hook .

Comment: It sounds to me as if the following is happening.

You are calling this.auth0login() in your mounted lifecycle.

You are redirected the the authentication page, get authenticated there, and you're then sent back to your page, where the mounted lifecycle runs again, and sends you to authentication again, creating an infinite loop.

If this is what is happening it, you can't stop it with return as you found out, since you leave the page when you are redirected, and the component is mounted again as you are redirected back.

Is this what is happening?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is what is happening. Is there a way to stop this? I just want to call the auth0login() once.

Comment: Yes, but the approach is a bit different. You need to have an if statement wrapping your this.auth0login() in mounted. When you have been by the auth0 authentication, you must have been given a token of some sort, i would assume that it's in your url?

If you just check in your mounted lifecycle
if(!checkIfTokenIsSet) { this.auth0login() }

you should be good